# How to reset locale back to original after changing it in Python?

Tags: python, locale

After changing the locale in a Python program, what is the safe way to change it back to its original value?

What I have tried so far is to store the original locale as returned by [`locale.getlocale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getlocale)
before making changes and then using [`locale.setlocale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) afterwards to change back to it.

Example program:

```python
import datetime
import locale

now = datetime.datetime.now()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print("Date using your locale      : %s" % now.strftime('%c'))

saved = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
print("Date using the C locale     : %s" % now.strftime('%c'))

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, saved)
print("Date using your locale again: %s" % now.strftime('%c'))
```

However, this does not always work as expected. It seems that the problem arises with locales that have a *modifier* (the bit after the '@' sign). Trying the following with Python 3.7 on a Debian 10 system illustrates the problem:

```
$ LC_TIME=sr_RS.utf8@latin python3 example.py
Date using your locale      : četvrtak, 01. avgust 2019. 14:43:43 
Date using the C locale     : Thu Aug  1 14:43:43 2019
Date using your locale again: четвртак, 01. август 2019. 14:43:43
```

So it appears to change back to the `sr_RS.utf8` locale instead of the original `sr_RS.utf8@latin` locale, forgetting about the `@latin` modifier.

Furthermore, if the corresponding locale without the modifier is not available, there will be an error when trying to switch back. For example on a system where the `nan_TW.utf8@latin` locale is present, but `nan_TW.utf8` is not:

```
$ LC_TIME=nan_TW.utf8@latin python3 example.py
Date using your locale      : 2019 8g 01 (p4) 14:44:29 
Date using the C locale     : Thu Aug  1 14:44:29 2019
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 13, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, saved)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 604, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Is there a safe way to switch back to the original locale setting? Something that could be used for example in a library routine intended to be used within a larger locale-aware program to temporarily switch the locale (for example, for formatting dates in another locale) and then switching it back, without permanently interfering with the locale of the calling program.

Comment: Is the problem with getting it or setting it? Try printing `saved`

Comment: The problem appears to be in getting the locale. When running the latter example, the `getlocale` call returns the tuple `('nan_TW', 'UTF-8')`, where the `@latin` modifier is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a safe way to switch back to the original locale setting? (if it uses modifiers as e.g. `latin`)

No, not with standard function calls: `locale.getlocale()` ignores all modifiers except `euro`, see [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c9a484a1e76384680b90454018389465760dbeae/Lib/locale.py#L488).

A workaround is to use the internal function `_setlocale`, i.e. reverse engineer `getlocale` without the `_parse_localename` part:

```
import datetime
import locale

now = datetime.datetime.now()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print("Date using your locale      : %s" % now.strftime('%c'))

saved = locale._setlocale(locale.LC_TIME)

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
print("Date using the C locale     : %s" % now.strftime('%c'))

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, saved)
print("Date using your locale again: %s" % now.strftime('%c'))
```

Example:

```
$ LC_TIME=sr_RS.utf8@latin python3 so57312038.py
Date using your locale      : sreda, 21. avgust 2019. 00:00:29 
Date using the C locale     : Wed Aug 21 00:00:29 2019
Date using your locale again: sreda, 21. avgust 2019. 00:00:29
```